# No module named 'services'

Tags: python

**`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'services'`**

Totally new to Python, please pardon for this stupid question. I'm following a nice tutorial which has this structure:
[image]

`deskew_service.py` has this line looks perfect as it tries to import from another file in the same folder where it has `class GraphicsService():`

[image]

After reading other SO posts, Python 3.x would use `from .<folder/package> import <classname>`, but  `from .services import GraphicsService` still the same.

Running this script tests\test_deskew.py contains the following got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'services'`

[image]

Python v 3.9.5

Comment: Try adding an empty file `services/__init__.py`

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: `deskew_service.py` should use relative path `from .graphics_service import GraphicsSErvice` without `service`

Comment: you could use `import service` or `from service.... import ...` if you would append `/full/path/tp/python-service` to `sys.path` before `import` but it is better to use relative path.

Comment: @furas Thank you very much for the suggestions!

Comment: @jakub Thank you and I'll study `__init__.py`.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee Will do, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @furas and @jakub. Here are the "how":

- among classes in same folder/package,  *from .filename import classname*, for example from above, `from .graphics_service import GraphicsService`.
- in sibling folder, *from ..foldername import classname*, i.e. `from ..services import DeskewService`